# $H^2(\mathrm{im}(f))$ is infinite cyclic for any generic immersion $f\colon S^2\to S^4$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Just to give the context: this appeared while defining an invariant for a 2-dimensional link map $(f_1,f_2)\colon S^2\coprod S^2\to S^4$ (in "*The Group of Disjoint 2-Spheres in 4-Space*" by Schneiderman and Teichner.)
Specifically, they deform the link map into a generic immersion, and use the Hurewicz maps, Alexander duality and the title to get
$$
\pi_1(S^4\setminus\mathrm{im}(f_i))\twoheadrightarrow H_1(S^4\setminus\mathrm{im}(f_i))\cong H^2(\mathrm{im}(f_i))\cong\mathbb{Z},$$
and thus are able to consider Wall's intersection number $\lambda(f_i,f_i)$ with values in the group ring $\mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{Z}]$.

I have no clue on computing the homology of the image of generic immersions (or any continuous maps,) so any idea or suggestion would be very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every continuous function with compact domain and Hausdorff range is a quotient map onto its image. In particular, a generic immersion $S^2 \mapsto S^4$ is a quotient map onto its image, under which certain two point subsets are identified to single points.

The image of a generic immersion $S^2 \mapsto S^4$ is therefore homeomorphic to a quotient space of $S^2$ obtained from a partition of $S^2$ whose only nontrivial partition elements are a collection of two points subsets $\{x_1,y_1\}$, $\{x_2,y_2\}$, ..., $\{x_n,y_n\}$. In other words: identify $x_1$ to $y_1$, and then $x_2$ to $y_2$, and so on, finally identifying $x_n$ to $y_n$.

Now calculate the homology of this quotient space. There's a variety of ways to do this, for example: by an induction argument using a Mayer-Vietoris sequence in the induction step; or by constructing a CW complex structure on the quotient space. You should get $H_2 \approx \mathbb Z$, and $H_1 \approx \mathbb Z^n$. I'm also pretty sure this example is found in various topology textbooks, such as Hatcher's "Algebraic Topology".